# Error : no response while calling php web service from java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have this script with me which calls a php webservice

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> ```
>         });
>         function sendPushNotification(id){
>             var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
>             $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
>             $.ajax({
>                 url: "send_push_notification_message.php",
>                 type: 'GET',
>                 regId: data,
>               message: data,
>                 beforeSend: function() {
>
>                 },
>                 success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
>                       $('.push_message').val("");
>                 },
>                 error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
>
>                 }
>             });
>             return false;
>         }
>     </script>
> ```

sendPushNotification function:

```
<?php
 require_once('loader.php');

    $gcmRegID    = $_GET["regId"]; // GCM Registration ID got from device
    $pushMessage = stripUnwantedHtmlEscape($_GET["message"]);


    if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {


        $registatoin_ids = array($gcmRegID);
        $message = array("price" => $pushMessage);

        $result = send_push_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

        echo $result;
    }
?>
```

i am trying to pass certain values through a php page but when i try to pass values through the web page , nothing happens..
can anyone tell me the problem here ? help appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Shoudn't it be `send_push_notification_message.php` ?? on your AJAX code.

Comment: my bad. corrected..but still not working

Comment: You have declared `sendPushNotification()` but you have not called `sendPushNotification()`

Comment: @krishna this is what i have done

onchange="$('#<?php echo $rowUsers["gcm_regid"];?>').val(this.value);

Comment: `onchange= `  ??? do you mention onchange in html ?

Comment: @krishna here is the file link -
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9A4AEF2D01B99AAB%21107

Comment: @JAY you are just making `textarea` as blank if you receive success. so instead of making it as blank display `data`  in that textarea like this  `$('.push_message').val(data);`. also try in error part of ajax also same thing to find that whether your php file has any error.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
regId: data,
```

to this:

```
data: data,
```

or this:

```
data: {regId : data},
```

`regId` is not available in the jQuery ajax.